# Zeroing an Unusual Array

Tags: c, designated-initializer

I have a bit of C code, reproduced below. It is my understanding that it is setting certain bits of the BootPML4 array to a certain value. Could someone please explain how the `BootPML4` array below is filled? Also, how do I ensure that unused values in the array are zeroed, while ensuring that the two settings below remain intact?

```
typedef uint64_t pml4_entry_t;
#define PML4_PROT (INTEL_PTE_VALID | INTEL_PTE_WRITE)
pml4_entry_t BootPML4[PTE_PER_PAGE] __attribute__((section("__HIB, __bootPT"))) = {
    [0]                 = ((uint64_t)(PAGE_SIZE) | PML4_PROT),
    [KERNEL_PML4_INDEX] = ((uint64_t)(PAGE_SIZE) | PML4_PROT),
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is using *designated initializers* which was added in *C99*, The *Forward* section of the [C99 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) standard in paragraph *5* says:

> [...] Major changes from the previous edition include:

and has the following bullet:

> — designated initializers

and the details are covered in section `6.7.8` *Initialization* and provides the following example in paragraph *36* and *37*:

> EXAMPLE 12 Space can be ‘‘allocated’’ from both ends of an array by using a single designator:
>
> ```
> int a[MAX] = {
>   1, 3, 5, 7, 9, [MAX-5] = 8, 6, 4, 2, 0
> };
> ```
>
> In the above, if MAX is greater than ten, there will be some zero-valued elements in the middle; if it is less
>   than ten, some of the values provided by the first five initializers will be overridden by the second five.

The [gcc doc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) on *designated initializers* has a better example:

> To specify an array index, write ‘[index] =’ before the element value. For example,
>
> int a[6] = { [4] = 29, [2] = 15 };
>
> is equivalent to
>
> int a[6] = { 0, 0, 15, 0, 29, 0 };
>
> The index values must be constant expressions, even if the array being initialized is automatic.

Comment: It's not a gcc extension. It's a standard C feature as of the 1999 ISO standard. (Well, I suppose it's an extension if you're compiling in pre-C99 mode.)

Comment: @KeithThompson yeah, have no used it myself, I realized that after reading the intro again was looking for a standard example.

Comment: Your answer still says it's an extension. I think it's more relevant that it's a standard feature of the C language.

Comment: I hate to be picky (actually that's a lie, I *love* to be picky), but it would be worth mentioning in your answer that it's a standard C feature and not something gcc-specific.

Comment: @KeithThompson no problem, I wish more SO users were as picky, especially wrt to accepting answers but that is another topic. I completely updated my answer, it was more involved then I originally thought.